# Обработка множество кнопок одним методом C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

На форме есть 8 кнопок, с Background=Green. При нажатии на одну из 8 кнопок, она меняет цвет, допустим на желтый. Теперь как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на другую кнопку, желтая кнопка становилась опять зеленой, а выбранная желтой. Примерно представляю как это сделать, но в каждом событии нажатия кнопки писать изменения цвета на каждую, не охота. Binding использовать? А как?

Comment: Способ здорового программиста - использовать mvvm

Comment: Способ курильщика — подписать все кнопки на один хендлер, при клике всем выставлять зеленый, а потом sender'у ставить желтый

Comment: @tym32167, а стилизовать RadioButton и не писать c#-код вообще — чей способ? :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP это уже для профи :)